# Nested NIntegrate with variables in limits

Tags: numerical-integration

How do I solve nummerically something like this and plot a function for it?

$f(x)=\int \exp[\int ^{x+y} _{x-y} \exp(z) dz]dy  $

This example has analytical solution, however I would like to know how inegrals like these can be integrated nummerically, when there is no analytic solution.

I tried something like:

```
f1[y_, x_?NumericQ] := f1[y] = NIntegrate[Exp[z], {z, x - y, x + y}]
f2[x_?NumericQ] := f2[x] = NIntegrate[Exp[f1[y, x]], {y, -Infinity, x}]
Plot[ f2[x], {x, -10., 10}]'
```

and it didn't work at all.

Comment: Why no `?NumericQ` on the `y`?

Comment: A double integral is faster than nested integrals: `f3[x_?NumericQ] := 
 f3[x] = NIntegrate[Exp[Exp[z]], {y, -Infinity, x}, {z, x - y, x + y}]`....But I wonder about the inverted limits of integration when `y` is negative.

Answer (score 2):

```
Clear[f1, f2]
```

Your first integral can be done symbolicly. This will speed up the final integration.

```
f1[y_, x_] = Integrate[Exp[z], {z, x - y, x + y}]

(*  2 E^x Sinh[y]  *)

f2[x_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[Exp[f1[y, x]], {y, -Infinity, x}]

Plot[f2[x], {x, -10, Pi/4}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]